# Keras Tokenizer num_words doesn't seem to work

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, tokenize

```
>>> t = Tokenizer(num_words=3)
>>> l = ["Hello, World! This is so&#$ fantastic!", "There is no other world like this one"]
>>> t.fit_on_texts(l)
>>> t.word_index
{'fantastic': 6, 'like': 10, 'no': 8, 'this': 2, 'is': 3, 'there': 7, 'one': 11, 'other': 9, 'so': 5, 'world': 1, 'hello': 4}
```

I'd have expected `t.word_index` to have just the top 3 words. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63658573/10375049

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in what you are doing. `word_index` is computed the same way no matter how many most frequent words you will use later (as you may see [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/text.py#L160)). So when you will call any transformative method - `Tokenizer` will use only three most common words and at the same time, it will keep the counter of all words - even when it's obvious that it will not use it later.

Comment: So `num_words` has no bearing on `fit_on_texts()` either?

Answer (score 10):

Just a add on Marcin's answer ("it will keep the counter of all words - even when it's obvious that it will not use it later.").

The reason it keeps counter on all words is that you can call `fit_on_texts` multiple times. Each time it will update the internal counters, and when transformations are called, it will use the top words based on the updated counters.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Limiting **num_words** to a small number (eg, 3) has no effect on **fit_on_texts outputs** such as **word_index, word_counts, word_docs**. It does have effect on **texts_to_matrix**. The resulting matrix will have **num_words** (3) columns.

```
>>> t = Tokenizer(num_words=3)
>>> l = ["Hello, World! This is so&#$ fantastic!", "There is no other world like this one"]
>>> t.fit_on_texts(l)
>>> print(t.word_index)
{'world': 1, 'this': 2, 'is': 3, 'hello': 4, 'so': 5, 'fantastic': 6, 'there': 7, 'no': 8, 'other': 9, 'like': 10, 'one': 11}

>>> t.texts_to_matrix(l, mode='count')
array([[0., 1., 1.],       
       [0., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little bit to farid khafizov's answer,
words at sequence of num_words and above are removed from the results of texts_to_sequences (4 in 1st, 5 in 2nd and 6 in 3rd sentence disappeared respectively)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

print(tf.__version__) # 2.4.1, in my case
sentences = [
    'I love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=4)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
print(word_index)  # {'love': 1, 'my': 2, 'i': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cat': 5, 'you': 6}
print(seq)         # [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```