# Use of num_words in the tokenizer class in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

Wanted to understand the difference between,

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

O/P - `{'love': 1, 'my': 2, 'i': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cat': 5, 'you': 6}`

vs

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

O/P - `{'love': 1, 'my': 2, 'i': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cat': 5, 'you': 6}`

If the tokeniser dynamically indexes all the unique words, what's the use of `num_words`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

word_index it's simply a mapping of words to ids for the entire text corpus passed whatever the num_words is

the difference is evident in the usage. for example, if we call `texts_to_sequences`

```
sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 1+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[1], [1], [1]]
```

only the love id is returned because the most frequent word

instead

```
sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 100+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 5], [6, 1, 2, 4]]
```

the ids of the most 100 frequent words is returned

Comment: Just one more question @MarcoCerliani, why does num_words = 1 give an empty mapping?

Comment: yes, the first token (the id 0) is always reserved... consider always num_token +1