# What is the actual use of num_words parameter in keras Tokenizer? How much overall does it affect the accuracy of my model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, nltk

In the given line of code `tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=, oov_token= '<OOV>')`, what does the num_words parameter actually do and what to take into consideration before determining the value to assign to it. What will be the effect of assigning a very high value to it and a very low one.

Comment: This might be helpful because it contains also the example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202519/keras-tokenizer-num-words-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the size of vocabulary you want to have it in your model based on the data you have. Below simple example will explain you in detail.

**Without num_words:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer  = Tokenizer(oov_token='<OOV>')
fit_text = ["Example with the first sentence of the tokenizer"]
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)
test_text = ["Example with the test sentence of the tokenizer"]
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_text)

print("sequences : ",sequences,'\n')

print("word_index : ",tokenizer.word_index) 

print("word counts : ",tokenizer.word_counts) 

sequences :  [[3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 2, 8]] 

word_index :  {'<OOV>': 1, 'the': 2, 'example': 3, 'with': 4, 'first': 5, 'sentence': 6, 'of': 7, 'tokenizer': 8}
word counts :  OrderedDict([('example', 1), ('with', 1), ('the', 2), ('first', 1), ('sentence', 1), ('of', 1), ('tokenizer', 1)])
```

Here `tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)` will create the `word_index` of the words mentioned present in `fit_text` in the order starting from `oov_token` which will be 1 and followed by most frequent words from the `word_counts`.
If you don't mention `num_words` then all the unique words of `fit_text` will be considered for `word_index` and will be used to represent the `sequences`.

If the `num_words` is present then it will restrict the sequences to `num_words -1` words from `word_index` will only be considered to form the sequence while using `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences()` if any word is present beyond `num_words -1` it will be considered as `oov_token`.
Below is the example of it.

**With use of num_words:**

```
tokenizer  = Tokenizer(num_words=4,oov_token='<OOV>')
fit_text = ["Example with the first sentence of the tokenizer"]
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(fit_text)
test_text = ["Example with the test sentence of the tokenizer"]
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_text)

print("sequences : ",sequences,'\n')

print("word_index : ",tokenizer.word_index)

print("word counts : ",tokenizer.word_counts) 

sequences :  [[3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]] 

word_index :  {'<OOV>': 1, 'the': 2, 'example': 3, 'with': 4, 'first': 5, 'sentence': 6, 'of': 7, 'tokenizer': 8}
word counts :  OrderedDict([('example', 1), ('with', 1), ('the', 2), ('first', 1), ('sentence', 1), ('of', 1), ('tokenizer', 1)])
```

Regarding the accuracy of the model it's always better to have the correct representation of the words in sequences from your data instead of `oov_token`.
In case of large data it's always better to provide the num_words parameter instead of giving load to model.
It's a good practice to do the preprocessing like `stopword removal,lemmatization/stemming` to remove all the unnecessary words and then followed by `Tokenizer` with the preprocessed data to choose the `num_words` parameter better.